# Installing Ubuntu on a new HDD, no previous operating system

Tags: installation

Alright, so I put aside my 250 gig hard drive and installed my 1TB (after formatting it). now the question is why won't any of my booters work, It says: Boot and Select proper boot device insert boot Media in selected boot deice and press a key. I have the bootable USB and live DVD but they won't work. When formatting should my hard drive be no drive letter and NTFS or exFAT or leave it as unallocated space?

Am I missing something? I've already gone through the Ubuntu install tips and still no luck. I've tried wubi installer for windows (through laptop) and installed it to my Fdrive but after installing like that it wouldn't work when I moved it to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your BIOS to boot from CD or flash disk yet? when the system says that insert proper boot media means that it can not find the boot media, open your BIOS setting, and choose to boot from CD/DVD or usb first.. if it fails again tell us.

Comment: the cd/dvd is not an option for some reason.. and have just tried for USB  when the HDD is NTFS and exFAT. im going to now try unalocated space (keep in mind that the first 2 tries while they were formatted did not have a letter associated with them.

Comment: now with unalocated space i got this error (i can't make out the first word of each line so im goessing on the last two for error and root Not sure whats before Default though guessing its NO.

LINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anivin et al

ERROR: No configuration file found
NO DEFAULT or UI Configuration directive found!
Root:

and thats with choosing to boot with usb.

Comment: Okay turns out every time i with the usb stick in an the boot with usb wasn't primary, it changed the file extentions and names to some sort of eastern asian language. so then when i booted from the USB it would output another error.

so I again did a fresh usb extraction of the ubuntu 12.10 32bit and now i get 

LINUX 4.06 EDD Load error - Boot error.

Some info on the usb. its a 20 gig. and formatted as FAT32. I can not format that to exFat nor can I format it to NTFS, it just fails.

Comment: I did something else in my bios and now when i boot from usb or UEFI USB i get a nice black screen with no error.. but no luck.

Comment: gonna try and see if its the version of ubuntu that's maybe not working. gonna see if Fed... another distro works. just as a test. if it does ill also add ubuntu (another version)

Comment: nope. same thing. black screen win Fedora 18. no error at least. im gonna keep this running for a few hours while im in class ill be back at roughly around 6:30 my time so another about 12 hours from now. hopefully less. ill be available on here thought at school. wish me luck. keep me updated.

Comment: Did you have Windows 8 with UEFI? If so this is a special case. As for the 32 bit version, check out my comment on your other posts, you should probably be using the 64-bit version (though the 32 should also work).

Comment: no windows. only linux. and i have not had any prior operating systems on this hard drive only files. and and i know about the whole 64 and 32 bit differences. it just wont process all 64 bits that its capable of it will only use 32bits.  it would just be more bang for my buck if i used 64. i just bought a new USB just incase its the usb thats corrupt its self. its quite an old one. just a precaution that I'm going to take.I should be home a lot sooner than i thought. Am I able to upload Images here? or input links to images from another website hosting them? if so I can try to take pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Ubuntu is using a LiveCD or USBStick. If your computer does not dectect them, you have to enter the BIOS and change that (Unless you have UEFI or EFI, but that is another case). If pressing F12 didn't show the BIOS menu, than there must be another key for that. The key that you press to access to the BIOS menu depends from machine to machine, in my CLEVO I have to press F7 or F2. You have to find out the correct key for your machine, and once you access the BIOS menu, you must change the boot priority to boot from CD first or USB stick first.

Comment: yeah its the Del button. and i do have UEFI. well I have the option for it. and my Bios is UEFI if that means i do have it.

Comment: Now, this is something you should have mentioned. Regardless, I found a guide that may solve your problem: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Let us know how it ended!

Comment: Why in the world is it this intense when I didn't have to do this last time? oh you know why? cause last time the hard drive was in another computer, another MoBo. etc. frig.

Comment: and thank you . im downloading the new ubuntu now. I really appreciate all the hard work you guys have been doing. ill continue progress reports.

Comment: I can't seem to find the disable Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). I was able to disable the fastboot. but I can't find the other one.i found a S.M.A.R.T but not 100% sure

Comment: yeah, no S.M.A.R.T. was not it.

Comment: Turns out the usb that i'm using is old and can't format to anything else other than fat 32. i went out last night, i bought a 16 gig usb. but somewhere on my way home it fell out of my bag. im gonna get yet another one today. (that usb falls apart and the case falls out of my hand when removing it from the port from behind my computer.

Comment: Man oh man, you gotta be careful!  Btw, SMART allows for tests that detect your disk health (I recommend it, you should run it in your old HDD).
What is SMART? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. 
SMART_Tools https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: ALSO; check this link, it is probably easier: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/how-to-run-hdd-smart-tests-in-ubuntu-linux/

I know you bought a new HDD, but have nothing to lose to check your old HDD health status.

Comment: got it to work thank you all for everything. it was the USB that messing it up. because i couldn't format the usb to NTFS> I bought two new usb's that are able to be formatted in NTFS, FAT32, FAT, exFAT. I learned in school (Operating System) you should when installing multiple operating systems to start with windows because linux can have a hard time recognizing windows. is it possible to install linux then windows after that on another partition? im installing ubuntu, then fedora, and then Windows. possible? thoughts?

Comment: It is possible, though highly NOT RECOMMENDED. If you want to have windows and then some linux distro, just install windows first and linux afte. Windows boot system is "very unike" and it will likely corrupt your linux GRUB if you install it after.